# send dynamic array via post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a form with 1 array and 1 optional array. The first array is static, 5 fields with from name="first_array[0]" to name="first_array[4]".

The second array would be added with onclick="addChannels(this.form);"

```
function addChannels(form) {

    for (var i = 1; i < 31; i++) {

        var checkbox = $("#checkbox-" + i);
        var slider = $("#slider-" + i);

        if ($(checkbox).is(":visible") && $(checkbox).is(":checked")) {
            $(slider).attr("name", "client_service[]"); // also can be i-1 to match the array positions
        }
    }

    // Finally submit the form.
    form.submit();
}
```

And this is the post, in the same page:

```
if (@$_POST['client_service_info'] && @$_POST['client_service']) {

    $client_service_info = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'client_service_info', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
    $client_service = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'client_service', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
    print 'acb: ' . $client_service[10] . '<br>agasegase: ' . $client_service_info[3];
    if ($client_info && $client_service_info) {
        $msg = $client->addServices($client_service_info, $client_service);
    }
}
```

I tried filling the form but it's not working, also trying printing the arrays but nothing is printed.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that I was trying to get a value from the slider itself not from the input where I put the ui.value.

So replace the span tags or whatever you are using to print the value with an input type text:

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#result").val(ui.value); // val instead of html or text
}
```

You can also customize your inputs to make them transparents (not the numbers):

```
input[type="text"]{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 15px;
    cursor: default;
}
```